# MySQL Left Outer Join on Wildcards

Tags: mysql, left-join, outer-join

I have two tables of DNS Data. One table `pdns.pdns` contains full dns queries while the other `pdns.adservers` contains a list of cdns/ad servers that I want to negate from my results.

Example data:

`pdns.adservers` :

```
+------+-----------------+
| Id   | addomain        |
+------+-----------------+
| 4100 | akamaiedge.net  |
| 4102 | akamai.net      |
| 4103 | akadns.net      |
+------+-----------------+
```

`pdns.pdns`:

```
+----------+-------------------------------------+
| ID       | QUERY                               |
+----------+-------------------------------------+
| 33062057 | 0.courier-push-apple.com.akadns.net |
|  3777954 | 0.dr.skype-cr.akadns.net            |
|  3777955 | 0.dr.skype-cr.akadns.net            |
|  3777956 | 0.dr.skype-cr.akadns.net            |
|  3777957 | 0.dr.skype-cr.akadns.net            |
|  6666666 | subdomain.domainiwant.com           |
+----------+-------------------------------------+
```

I am trying to do a Join on the data so if any fuzzy domain in `pdns.adservers.addomain`, i.e. `%akadns.net%` would not return in my results. In other words, using the tables above, I would want my query to only return **subdomain.domainiwant.com** from `pdns.pdns`.

Here is what I have come up with and been playing with to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated! thank you!

```
SELECT DISTINCT `QUERY`,`TTL` FROM `pdns`.`pdns` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pdns.adservers AS badzone 
ON pdns.`QUERY` NOT LIKE CONCAT('%', badzone.addomain, '%') 
WHERE badzone.addomain IS NULL AND TTL < 300 LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: why concat?  is it necessary?

Comment: @tonygil I assumed i had to concat because i need the results in `pdns.addomain` to be fuzzy. i.e. instead of `akadns.net` i want to search against `%akadns.net` to make sure i'm ignoring any subdomains for `*.akadns.net`

Comment: I see, you don't like adservers. But you have to use `LIKE` instead of `NOT LIKE` :-)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel holy crap it was that easy the whole time. *facepalm*. THANKS!!